Gradle Error: Could not find com.github.jiangdongguo.AndroidUSBCamera:libausbc:3.3.3 Dependency
I am making an android app using java where I want to show the video stream coming form an Webcam connected via USB cable to my android phone. I'm encountering an issue with resolving the following dependency in my Android project:
implementation 'com.github.jiangdongguo.AndroidUSBCamera:libausbc:3.3.3'

When building the project, I get the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.                                                                                                                                
   > Could not find com.github.jiangdongguo.AndroidUSBCamera:libausbc:3.3.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera/libausbc/3.3.3/libausbc-3.3.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/jiangdongguo/AndroidUSBCamera/libausbc/3.3.3/libausbc-3.3.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

My Questions:

Has anyone faced a similar issue with this library or other dependencies hosted on JitPack?
What could be causing this dependency to fail to resolve, even though the repository and version seem correct?
Are there any other possible solutions to resolve this dependency?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried these:

Checked JitPack Repository:

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}


I have confirmed that version 3.3.3 exists on JitPack, and I've tried different versions, but the issue persists.
I have tried the new library catalog declaration: implementation libs.libausbc

